# Force PHP json_encode() to encode indexes as strings

Tags: php, json

I have a an array setup as follows:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[] = "New array item 1";
$myArray[] = "New array item 2";
$myArray[] = "New array item 3";
```

When I run json_encode() on it it outputs the following:

```
["New array item 1","New array item 2","New array item 3"]
```

What I want is for the function to encode the indexes as strings:

```
{"0":"New array item 1","1":"New array item 2","2":"New array item 3"}
```

So that later I can remove say the first item without affecting the index of the second.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`:

```
json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
```

Requires PHP 5.3+

Comment: Is there no other way? I wanted to keep it as an array.

Comment: @bbeckford what do you mean? You'll still have the original array, it is not mutated or removed

Comment: Well for instance I wouldn't be able to do this would I?

    $decodedArray = json_decode('{"0":"New array item 1","1":"New array item 2","2":"New array item 3"}');
    $decodedArray[] = "New array item 4";
    json_encode( $decodedArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );

Comment: @bbeckford If you're planning to use this array in JavaScript, it's best to know that the syntax doesn't allow Arrays with such indexes anyway. You'll get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.

Comment: @bbeckford you should pass `true` as second parameter to `json_decode`

Comment: @Esailija Ah I didn't know about that part of json_decode, that did it thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you want but you can use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option:

```
json_encode($myArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

which would produce:

```
{"0":"New array item 1","1":"New array item 2","2":"New array item 3"}
```

Same if you cast your array to object:

```
json_encode((object)$myArray);
```

Alternatively:

```
$myArray = array(
  "0" => "New array item 1",
  "2" => "New array item 2",
  "3" => "New array item 3"
  );

 echo json_encode($myArray);
```

would give same:

```
{"0":"New array item 1","2":"New array item 2","3":"New array item 3"}
```

Comment: This works only if indexes are not continous.
"When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and specified explicitly for each key-value pair."

Comment: @morgar: Read the manual again. It works for all cases because that's what `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is for.

Comment: 5.3 release date is 30 June 2009, so what argument is that?

Answer (score 3):

For PHP < 5.3 , use this method :

```
<?php   

$myArray = array();
$myArray[] = "New array item 1";
$myArray[] = "New array item 2";
$myArray[] = "New array item 3";

echo json_encode((object)$myArray); // typecast the array as object

?>
```